# Measuring (i times) a commutator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Suppose I have a line of $n$ spin-1/2 particles and I define two observables:

$A = -1$ if all the spins are spin-up in the $z$-direction, 1 otherwise

$B = -1$ if all the spins are spin-up in the $x$-direction, 1 otherwise.

The operator $i[A,B]$ is Hermitian, so it's an observable.  What operation do I do on the spins to measure it?